# Not able to use select distinct and group by together in impala query

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate, distinct, impala

`select distinct actor, count(id) from table group by actor;`

Table

```
actor   id
a        2
a        2
b        1
b        2
```

Impala is throwing error as:

> AnalysisException: cannot combine SELECT DISTINCT with aggregate
>   functions or GROUP BY

Comment: While it is surprising that Impala cannot combine the two, what would you gain? By grouping by actor, all rows are already distinct. Even if you could apply `DISTINCT`, it would be superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count rows with not null id per actor, then you do not need distinct at all, because you have group by and each actor group with it's id count will be selected only once:

```
select actor, count(id) from table group by actor; --counts not null id rows per actor
```

You can apply distinct to the id column if you want to calculate only distinct id's for each actor. For your data example count(distinct id) for actor='a' wiil give you 1 and for actor='b' it will be 2:

```
select actor, count(distinct id) from table group by actor; --counts distinct not null id per actor
```

Read more about [Impala DISTINCT](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/impala_distinct.html).

Comment: Thanks leftjoin. Why impala is giving an error when using select distinct and group by? Same thing work in oracle.

Comment: @rks And what such query returns in Oracle? Because DISTINCT in your query applies to returned columns, but GROUP BY already makes it distinct, so the syntax is not correct one, though different databases may support their own sysntax. Use the second query if you need to count distinct IDs, in that case DISTINCT will be applied to ID column